Typescript how to extract multiple literal from a string
type X<T>=T extends `${string}${'*('}${infer A}${')+'}${string}${'*('}${infer A}${')+'}${string}`?A:never

type Y=X<'g*(a12)+gggggg*(h23)+'> // 'a12' | 'h23'

type z=X<'g*(a12)+gggggg*(h23)+gggggg*(5hgf)+'> // 'a12' | 'h23' but without '5hgf'

My objective is to extract all literals from a string based on certain pattern. In the code above, I wanna extract literals with prefix '*(' and postfix ')+'. Hence, type Y =  'a12' | 'h23'.
But the problem is a string can have any number of matched-pattern-literal and I do not know how to let typescript to extract all the matched literals.
For the code example, Typescript only extracts 2 literals because I write two times of ${string}${'*('}${infer A}${')+'}. If I write  type z=X<'g*(a12)+gggggg*(h23)+gggggg*(5hgf)+'>, I still get type Z = 'a12' | 'h23''. Ideally, I should get type Z = 'a12' | 'h23'|''5hgf''
How to make typescript to 'iterate' through the string to get all the desired literals?
Thank you!

Why is "gggggg" not a "literal with surrounding '*'" in your example?

(see prev comment) Assuming you do mean single characters and not just "literal", then you'll want a recursive solution that walks through the string, such as the one shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Is your "better example" supposed to be an addition or a replacement to the first example? Could you pick one of these to ask about? You don't need to format a question as a series of updates; just [edit] to the new version and interested parties can always look at edit history if they care about old states of the question.

@jcalz hi, sorry for the confusion. In first example, "gggggg" should be included if based on my first version of question. I have updated the question to meet my real needs. My real question should be: how to extract all literals with the pattern of "*(xxx)+" from a string?

You can do that like this, assuming xxx doesn't literally mean three characters (which is hard to understand because all of your examples are of that form... is that a coincidence or a requirement?) Does that now meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (after you [edit] to make the question self-contained and not a series of updates). If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Yeah, This 2nd link [link] (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=5.4.5&ssl=2&ssc=21&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAGgPAFShAHsCA7AJgZyj4AJwEsMBzAGigEFk1Nd8jSyoBeKDCANwkID52UJKnTY8AAwAkAbwIlyAX1kByAFQAKFcpmkAZnygBVHSoCUAam2z9hgEqKJUAPwAoKB9hw7VWgB9jQQAuGgBuV1dQSCgATSF4FTJNAEMARgAmSzJsnM0AC3SAZksVflcAenLPAD03KOgALXi4RJSMrJzs-KKOzs0AVjyyPRKyypq3SPBGwubWjTTMi06ujQLi5dW8rHWsvTIsfcOkjSxD7b1tvIArIbyOgaGRqzKgA) is exactly what I need! 'xxx' can be of any length and it was just coincidence I  wrote it as 3chars.

There's no iterative approach to this, but you can use an equivalent recursive approach. And if you write it as a tail-recursive form, then it will work for quite long strings, if you have them. Here's one way to do it:
type X<T extends string, A extends string = never> =
    T extends `${string}${'*('}${infer U}${')+'}${infer R}` ?
    X<R, A | U> : A;

We're still writing X<T> to parse string via template literal types, but now there's an accumulator type parameter A to keep track of the union of matches we've already collected. If you are given a string that matches your pattern, the type U will be the first matching portion, and the type R will be the rest of the string. Then we recurse with X<R, A | U>, which adds U to the existing A accumulator. Otherwise there are no matches, and we return A.
Let's test it out:
type Y = X<'g*(a12)+gggggg*(h23)+'>
//   ^? type Y = "a12" | "h23"
type Z = X<'g*(a12)+gggggg*(h23)+gggggg*(5hgf)+'>
//   ^? type Z = "a12" | "h23" | "5hgf"

Looks good.
Playground link to code
